# Windows 10: Slow accessing network drive after connected to VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

I connected to a VPN through Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client.

Then accessing files in shared network becomes very slow, took 30 seconds to open a text file in vim.

Any suggestions help, thank you!

Comment: is the shared network drive on the remote (vpn) side or the local side? Is the shared network drive Windows or nfs or something else? Is the text file very large or not? Does it take a lot of time to list the contents of a directory on the shared network drive or not? Are you using mobile internet from a remote location or fast fiber or something in between for the vpn connection?

Comment: If you access the local network files using names (and not TCP/IP addresses) it is possible that the VPN grabs your DNS and isn't able to resolve the local names. Can you ping these names in a command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I reckon David Anderson had the answer,
but nothing has improved in 10 years as far as I can see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103968/gvim-runs-very-slowly-when-editing-files-on-a-windows-share

David's answer (with a small edit):

> … I use Process Monitor from SysInternals.com and it revealed bad behavior when attempting to open "\server\TestTool\foo\ReadMe.TXT"

It first attempts a CreateFile (aka, Directory open) on "\serve\". Notice the last character is missing. This will cause 4 seconds to time out with "OBJECT PATH INVALID".

Then it tries CreateFile on "\server\TestToo\". Server name is correct
<del>by</del> ***but*** the last letter of "TestTool" is clipped. Again, a 3 second time out with "BAD NETWORK NAME".

Finally it gets it right and calls CreateFile on "\server\TestTool\" which works right away. Then CreateFile on "\server\TestTool\foo" which works right away. Then CreateFile on "\server\TestTool\foo\ReadMe.TXT" which works right away.

> I downloaded the source code and found the problem. They are using FindFirstFile() which is not supposed to be used on root directories or network shares. Bug in vim.